# R: find range of X

Tags: r

I divided the value of X into 5 boxes and calculated its joint probabilities.

In the example below, since there are lots of 2s in X, in the end I only have 4 boxes.

Example:

```
X <-c(1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7)
Y <-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
qX=quantile(X, 1:4/5) # find quantiles 20%,40%,60%,80%
qY=c(0,1)
dX=findInterval(X,qX,rightmost.closed=TRUE) 
dY=findInterval(Y,qY+0.001,rightmost.closed=TRUE)
pXY=xtabs(~dX+dY)/10 # joint distribution
rownames(pXY) <- paste("box",1:dim(pXY)[1],sep="")


> pXY
           dY
dX       0   1
box1    0.1 0.0
box2    0.1 0.4
box3    0.1 0.1
box4    0.1 0.1
```

Now I want to add one more column for the range of X in each box.
The desired table will be:

```
box1  [1,1]  0.1 0.0
box2  [2,3]  0.1 0.4
box3  [4,5]  0.1 0.1
box4  [6,7]  0.1 0.1
```

Comment: You stated a desired output and then posted code that achieved the output. What is the question you have?

Comment: I just want to have one more column for the range of X in each box. The pXY at the bottom does not provide the range of X.

Answer (score 1):

The output of `xtabs` or `table` is somewhat messy to add to. I would convert to `matrix`:

```
pXY2 <- pXY; class(pXY2) <- "matrix"
data.frame(r=t(sapply(split(X,dX),range)),pXY2)
#   r.1 r.2  X0  X1
# 0   1   1 0.1 0.0
# 2   2   3 0.1 0.4
# 3   4   5 0.1 0.1
# 4   6   7 0.1 0.1
```

Given the cutpoints used to make `dX`, the values of the boxes really are 0,2,3,4, not 1,2,3,4.

---

If you want to print the range with special formatting, consider writing a custom function:

```
brackem <- function(x) paste0("[",x[1],",",x[2],"]")
data.frame(r=tapply(X,dX,function(z)brackem(range(z))),pXY2)
#       r  X0  X1
# 0 [1,1] 0.1 0.0
# 2 [2,3] 0.1 0.4
# 3 [4,5] 0.1 0.1
# 4 [6,7] 0.1 0.1
```